# Why is the following code not throwing an error?

Tags: c++

When I input 123456,the following code generates 1 2 3 4 5 6
But since digits can only hold a single digit value, shouldn't this code throw an error?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char digit;
    cout << "Enter a six-digit number: ";
    for (int p = 1; p <= 6; p++) {
        cin>>digit;
        cout<<digit<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not clear why you think there should be an error. Doesnt the output confirm your hypothesis of each `char` holding a single letter only?

Comment: input is 123456 rather than 1 then 2 then 3 and so on

Comment: It only holds a single value, you're overwriting that value every time.

Comment: I am inputing 123456 all at once without any breaks or anything.

Comment: your input is `123456` and you read first `1` then `2` then `3` and so on...

Comment: It assigns the `1`, then prints the `1`, then it assigns the `2`, prints the `2`, etc. Only one value is assigned to it at a given time.

Comment: The input you give is buffered. The input you give the program is put into that buffer. And then you read it from `std::cin` you read one character at a time from that buffer.

Comment: Now I get it,thanks a lot.

Comment: @user463035818 Speak for yourself; I get compilation errors every day ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit there was something I intended to say, though if I read it again, the comment is rather nonsensical. Always glad to get critized ;)

Comment: @user463035818 Always glad to help :P :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `cin>>digit` you request **one** `char` from the `cin`  stream.

`std::cin` is of the type `istream` which is `basic_istream<char>`,  so it is basically a buffer of `char`.

And because of that `cin>>digit` will always be valid and removes one `char` from the stream and saves it in the `digit` as long as the input stream is in a valid state, and has data available.

Answer (score 2):

The first time through, `cin` doesn't "know" that you have not yet stored a value in `digits` (you may as well have, despite the lack of initialiser).

It does not know this the second or third or fourth or fifth or sixth time, either.

It just replaces what's already there with what it reads from the stream.

This is normal, expected behaviour and not a cause for error.

By the end of your program, `digits` contains the ASCII code (probably) of the character `'6'`. Just that one character. You're seeing multiple values output because you output each value individually in a loop.